# How to setup xampp in linux to serve unity webgl Builds?

Tags: xampp, unity-webgl

So I have a xampp server setup in windows for unity webgl builds and it works on both http as well as on https. The builds are decompressed on the fly and the game starts to play. I have used both compression methods, Brotli and gzip on http and https.

I followed the unity manual page for setting it up. [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-server-configuration-code-samples.html)

I changed the config files of the server to allow for mime packages to be loaded and for the htaccess files to override the directory settings. The htaccess file's content is copy pasted from unity manual.

Now I did the exact steps on Ubuntu but it gives the following error for brotli compressed files on http(works with gzip on http and https and with brotli on https).

```
Unable to parse Build/Build.framework.js.br!
If using custom web server, verify that web server is sending .br files 
with HTTP Response Header "Content-Encoding: br". Brotli compression may 
not be supported in Firefox over HTTP connections. See 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1670675 for more 
information.
```

I am using firefox on both windows and ubuntu.

Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "it doesn't work" - what does that mean? How is this related to "unity webgl content"?

Comment: I mean to say that it throws an error if i try to open localhost using http but works fine if i open it up using https.

Comment: "It throws an error" can mean a lot. Which kind of error are you facing? Please add the error message to your question by editing it (in text form, not hidden in screenshots!), along with the code that helps to reproduce the problem and your attempts to resolve it.

Comment: I think I know what happened.
Firefox has a bug which does not allow for brotli compression on http connections and I was using it for testing all this time Tested it on Chrome and Chromium It works

Comment: ....well, that would be a surprise. If only the error message would contain any hint about this......